# converting string to uint

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to read in a hex value from a text box and then put it in a uint, this is the code:

```
UInt32 x = Convert.ToUInt32(location_txtbox.ToString());
```

Why, I want to pass x to some unmanaged code and the function header requires a DWORD.

I'm getting an 'input string was not in correct format error?  I am trying to input values such as 0x7c or 0x777 but I keep getting errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this [overload of Convert.ToUInt32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swz6z5ks.aspx) where you specify the base of the conversion.  It should work with or without the leading "0x".

```
UInt32 x = Convert.ToUInt32(location_txtbox.Text, 16);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming location_txtbox is a TextBox, you may want to use .Text instead of .ToString().

And I think you need to pass 16 as the second parameter to parse hex: e.g. Convert.UInt32( X, 16)

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swz6z5ks.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToUInt32` just calls [`UInt32.Parse(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b23e5abt.aspx). If you call the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41810tes.aspx) that takes a `NumberStyles` parameter, you can specify your value is hexadecimal. Trouble is, you'll have to cut out the leading "0x", as it isn't allowed.

```
var hexNumber = "0x777".Substring(2);
uint.Parse(hexNumber, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

Answer (score 2):

A) Never use Convert without wrapping it in a try/catch, or unless you are VERY sure that what you are parsing will be parsed successfully.

B) Use uint.TryParse.  In particular, use the one that allows you to specify the number style. The reference for it is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kadka85s.aspx

C) in the style  it appears that you will need NumberStyles.HexSpecifier

D) Use the Text property, as stated above.

Comment: Thank you, yes I couldn't agree more.  This is just a test app for me and I know exactly what values are being passed so I won't get any errors; but yes normally I wrap everything.